# Javascript: I'm getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { "

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I get the following error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ) with this bit of code. The error is occurring with the '{' following the "else" portion of the code.

```
   var position = $(this).position();
    if (position>=0 && position<6684) {
        var decade = '1970s';
    } else if (position>=6684 && position<16373) {
        var decade = '1980s';
    } else if (position>=16373 && position<25711) {
        var decade = '1990s';
    } else if (position>=25711 && position<37503) {
        var decade = '2000s';
    } else (position>=37503 && position<42125) {
        var decade = '2010s';
    }
```

Comment: the else shouldn't have a condition ? else{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last else contains a condition just remove it and try again

```
 var position = $(this).position();
    if (position>=0 && position<6684) {
        var decade = '1970s';
    } else if (position>=6684 && position<16373) {
        var decade = '1980s';
    } else if (position>=16373 && position<25711) {
        var decade = '1990s';
    } else if (position>=25711 && position<37503) {
        var decade = '2000s';
    } else (position>=37503 && position<42125) { //FALSE CONDITION
        var decade = '2010s';
    }
```

**TRY**

```
 var position = $(this).position();
    if (position>=0 && position<6684) {
        var decade = '1970s';
    } else if (position>=6684 && position<16373) {
        var decade = '1980s';
    } else if (position>=16373 && position<25711) {
        var decade = '1990s';
    } else if (position>=25711 && position<37503) {
        var decade = '2000s';
    } else{ 
        var decade = '2010s';
    }
```

Comment: why not `} else if(position>=37503 && position<42125) {`?

Comment: yeah, actually you are not wrong, but maybe he just missed the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Because you've added a `(` in the line:

```
} else (position>=37503 && position<42125) {
    var decade = '2010s';
}
```

There should be another if statement:

```
} else if (position>=37503 && position<42125) {
    var decade = '2010s';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last else you miss `if` before condition

*Change*

```
} else (position>=37503 && position<42125) {
    var decade = '2010s';
}
```

*To*

```
} else if(position>=37503 && position<42125) {
    var decade = '2010s';
}
```